# Does redirecting to a mobile-friendly version of my site make it a responsive website, as far as Google is concerned?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Let's assume my site is not responsive at the moment. I can either modify the CSS and HTML to make it responsive (by using width techniques or even media functions in CSS) Now that will work 100% and make my site mobile-friendly.

Another solution is to create a whole new mobile template and just load it under a different site almost, so when a user accesses the site from a mobile device it redirects them to a new site "mobile.*websitename*.com".

Would that make the initial site (the unresponsive one without "mobile" in the domain) responsive from Google's point of view? Or is Google not smart enough to recognize that mobile users would be redirected to a mobile version of the site?

Comment: My **guess** is that Google will interpret this as two different sites **because they are**. You would get two rankings, one for each domain...I think.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hmm interesting, so you are saying theres no official announcements made by google in this matter, meaning its just down to expert opinions on what will happen.

Comment: @TZHX I woudld be creating a whole new directory for mobile, meaning not just new css but also new html and even php.

Comment: @TZHX Would you be kind enough to create an answer and tell me how i would construct such tags? Or at the bear minimum link me to resource which explains what i am after?

Comment: @TZHX Really appreciated

Comment: See this article (Q4 seems on point) - [**Linky**](http://moz.com/blog/9-things-about-googles-mobile-friendly-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google would **strongly prefer** you to create a truly responsive design. However, they also understand that this is not going to be possible for all people or budgets, and so are willing to work with less thorough solutions.

Assuming that you have your **main** site `www.example.com`, and you wish to make a separate **mobile** site at `m.example.com`.

On **each page** of your main site, you need to add the following in the header:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 320px)"
      href="http://m.example.com/****" >
```

Replacing `****` with the path to the appropriate page on your mobile site, and also tweaking the section in `media=` to the appropriate media-query you want the page to be used for. You can have several to cater to multiple screen sizes, if you wish.

> **N.B.:** This doesn't actually redirect users -- it is only for Google or other search engines (I know, that they still exist is shocking, right?) or features on phones browsers where users can explicitly request the mobile/desktop sites. You'll need to handle the redirection based on user-agent strings

Then, on each page of your mobile site, you need a similar link:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/****" >
```

Again, replacing `****` with the appropriate, corresponding page.

You can learn more about responsive design and what Google likes by viewing [their web pages on the subject](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/index?hl=en). *Just* redirecting the mobile users away without this markup may hinder Google in realising that you *are* serving well-formatted content to mobile users, and lead to your site being penalised from mobile searches.